# DXF overlay problem in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, dxf, autocad, inkscape

I need to import and overlay in my QGIS project some geometries from a PDF (definitely not georeferenced). I ran the PDF cleanup procedure on Inkscape and exported it as a DXF file.Next, I started a second project and there I created a custom CRS so that I could bring the layer closer to my point of interest, then I saved the layer as shapefile and set CRS 32632: the current situation is that the geometries are close to the city, but they are not overlapped and its dimensions are much larger than the layers of the project

here's the Custom CRS Settings. I entered Vado Ligure coordinates[image]

The one in red is the layer I want to put correctly over that rectangle on the left (tiff)[image]

I tried to use Vector Bender but without success. What possibilities do I have to go ahead and correctly overlap the geometries?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to georeference the PDF?

Comment: instead of continuing to use pdf to process the tiff for each project we would like to extract the lines directly from the pdf and then start the projects with only vector files...also because the tiff slows down QGIS a bit

Comment: The Plugin AnotherDXFImporter contains a module for georeferencing:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355220/re-scale-and-move-vector-layer-manually-in-qgis/355257#355257

Comment: is there a full guide? I'm new to this thing and I don't know much about coordinates settings

Comment: Can you explain what didn't work with Vector Bender? Did you make sure the Vector Bender line used for connecting source to destination was in the right CRS? If you used the one generated by the plugin, it's set to EPSG:4326 by default.